# R arbitrary ring, R/I is a field then I maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

In Foote and Dummit Page 255. It states: Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring (not necessary has 1) if $R/I$ is a field then I is maximal.

I know the statement holds when $R$ has 1, but how to prove this if $R$ does not have 1.

Comment: What happened when you read through the proof in the case that $R$ has $1$, and tried to make the proof work in the case that $R$ does not have $1$?

Comment: For non-commutative rings we need to distinguish between left, right and bilateral ideals, same for maximal. A field has no non-trivial ideals (left or right or bilateral it is the same since commutative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, take $J$ an ideal of $R$ such that contains $I$. We want to show that either $J=I$ or $J=R$.

Since $J$ is an ideal of $R$ then $J/I$ is an ideal $R/I$ consequently $J/I=\lbrace I\rbrace$ or $J/I=R/M$ as a result of being $R/I$ a field.

In the first case implies $a+I=I~\forall a\in J$, therefore $J=I$.

On the other hand if $J/I=R/I$, for every $r\in R$ exists an $a\in J$ s.t. $r+I=a+I$, then $r-a\in I\subset J$ and $a$ lies in $J$ so $r\in J$ for each $r\in R$.

Hence $J=I$ or $J=R$.